# selecting values from array with indexes and summing over them

Tags: python, performance, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays, values and indexes

```
>>> values
array([[5, 4, 2, 4, 6],
       [7, 9, 7, 3, 6]])
>>> indexes
array([[2, 4],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 3]])
```

What i would like is a fast way (as my arrays are very large) to get, for each value of values the sum of the elements corresponding to all index collections that are in indexes.

I.e I want, for the first value [5, 4, 2, 4, 6] to get

```
>>> values[0][indexes.flatten()].reshape(indexes.shape)
array([[2, 6],
       [5, 4],
       [5, 4],
       [4, 4]])

>>> values[0][indexes.flatten()].reshape(indexes.shape).sum(axis=1)
array([8, 9, 9, 8])
```

using this technique and looping over all values is the fastest I could come up with. Is there a better way? Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Simply index into columns and sum along the last axis -

```
values[:,indexes].sum(axis=-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: values
Out[39]: 
array([[5, 4, 2, 4, 6],
       [7, 9, 7, 3, 6]])

In [40]: indexes
Out[40]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 3]])

In [41]: values[:,indexes].sum(axis=-1)
Out[41]: 
array([[ 8,  9,  9,  8],
       [13, 10, 16, 12]])
```

**Approach #2**

If there are no duplicates in each row of `indexes`, we can simply use `matrix-multiplication` to get the `sum-reductions` and this would be much faster -

```
m,n = indexes.shape[0], values.shape[1]
mask = np.zeros((n,m),dtype=bool) # faster with float dtype
mask[indexes, np.arange(m)[:,None]] = 1
out = values.dot(mask)
```

Comment: Thx for suggestion. Your second approach worked for me, speeding things up by a factor of 10 . The first approach was in fact slower than the code with the loop i already had

Comment: @F.E Keep in mind the qualifier stated for Approach #2. Updated post.